Explorifying `\latex2e` code
The below code redefines a hyperref conditional using the expl3 language. The hyperref package uses this macro to check if a LaTeX2e counter is defined and then provides commands for theH<section> type of commands. One of my most common errors when programming using the l3 language is typing exists instead of exist, like in int_if_exists. Is there a particular reason as to why this was adopted? Also why is the prg module named prg? Was this somehow based on the pronunciation of predicate pron. /ˈprɛdɪkeɪt  ? Shouldn't this be prd?
\documentclass{article}
\def\TRUE{\par TRUE}
\def\FALSE{\par FALSE}
\makeatletter
\def\Hy@CounterExists#1{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname the#1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\Hy@CounterExists{section}{%
    \TRUE
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn
%% Example 1
\cs_new:Npn \__hyper_if_exist_counter:n #1
  {
    \int_if_exist:cTF {c@#1}{ \TRUE }{ \FALSE }
  }

\__hyper_if_exist_counter:n{chapter}
    
%% Example 2 as new predicate
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \hyper_if_exist_counter:n  #1 {p,T,F, TF}
{
  \int_if_exist:cTF {c@#1}{ \prg_return_true:}{ \prg_return_false: }
}

\hyper_if_exist_counter:nTF{section}{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
  
      
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother
\end{document}


I think that prg stands for programming, and I think that it's exist since you often prefer the imperative voice in programming. I'm not really certain though, so hopefully one of the LaTeX team members will have a more definitive answer.

@MaxChernoff Possible, although it does not make sense in the context where is being used.

True, although “predicate” isn't a great fit either for things like \prg_replicate:nn and \prg_break_point:Nn.

If you review the manual, \prg_ statements are listed under program flow, which includes many conditionals. expl was started in 1991, if I recall correctly, so there may be some historical burden here and there.

prg is programming (see section 9.9 of interface3 for example)  expl3 uses if_exist consistently for all types not just int so it is what it is (probably would have been better as exists but you can't change history)

@DavidCarlisle Thanks, I wasn't advocating anything to be renamed, I was just curious, I think I was born with an excess of curiosity and according to Chomsky grammar we also born with it.

It was decided long ago (the development of expl3 started along with the release of LaTeX2e) that each function or variable should belong to a module.

cs is for “control sequences”; not the best name in my opinion, but it's definitely too late.

prg is for “programming facilities” (the manual talks of “control structures”): conditionals are defined with \prg_new_conditional:Nnn, but they should belong to some other module; \prg_return_true: and \prg_return_false: belong to this category; \prg_replicate:nn belongs to nothing in particular.

int is for something related to integer arithmetic, including variables (aka registers);

…


The naming is not always strictly consistent, though. There's no scan module, but \scan_stop: exists. Similarly for \group_begin: and \group_end:. These functions fall in the (small) pool of “moduleless” functions, that are essentially (renamed) TeX primitives. Also the low level conditionals fall into this pool: \ifx: \fi: \else: and so on.
Why “exist” and not “exists”? Because all verbs in function names are in the “naked” form.
The …_if_exist:… functions are a rather recent addition, March 2012 or later. Discussion was done about “exist” vs. “exists”, finally deciding for the former.

Thanks. I find your comment about cs  interesting as I thought the same, why not fun for function since the new terminology or cmd for continuity with LaTeX2e?

@yannisl Because Frank started in 1991 with \cs_...

@yannisl think of it as an abbreviation for the existential quantifier? only there's nothing for the universal ....

@cfr  Yes... but more like the set of the rest of all sets...
